# Dart List Max Length

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the maximum number of items that a Dart List can store? I cant find any resources regarding the maximum length of a list. Dart API only mentioned growable list, but I am curious about the maximum number of elements a list can hold.

Comment: If the list is growable and dynamic, that it can be of any size till there is space in your memory.

Answer (score 4):

En, to your question, there's no limitation on how many items can be added to a list but you do have a restriction at hardware device which consumes memory to actually load the list it self.

That's why there are two main types of lists, with out a builder and the other with builder.

Using a list with out a builder, will load all elements on the list at once, which is perfect when you know in advance you won't have many, for example top ten articles, a drawer etc..

Using a list with builder, is basically used to prevent loading (in this lame example) 1000 records at once, rather load them on demand while you start scrolling and dismissing the items in memory when you scroll enough.

Think about this, if you have 10 items it should not be a problem using a normal list, but imagine you have 1000.

First, 1000 won't fit on the screen, each of them will consume a bit of memory leading to battery consumption and stuttering depending on performance. That's why when you know in advance you will have lots of items, using a list builder is recommended, flutter will dismiss previous elements of the list and load new ones while scrolling preventing the case I mention of using a normal list.

Comment: Hi, I think you got my question wrong. I am asking about the general list class, not the listview for rendering. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score -1):

So, about your question i'm not sure if there is a limit in dart list items count.
But, what we should do if there an limit !! in this case we must use if statement the check the list length if it reach the limit then store the data in second list.
the idea is to split your data in this case to multiple of lists.